# Mistake on visa application

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications

On my visitor visa to the UK application form,the question “have they always had the same nationality?”which is under parent details  I put No instead of Yes..and I have already paid and submitted my application but I haven’t been to the embassy..what can I do please advice ..and I plan on going to travel alone and not with any parent of mine

Comment: Usually there’s a pop up box or extra section to provide further details - what did you enter there? AFAIK, you can either cancel the application and start again, or you can correct the error in the hard copy of your application and ask the Embassy official to note the change when you go for your biometric appointment.

Comment: The pop up box just said what was there nationality when they gave birth to me and I mentioned her normal country which is where I was born

Comment: Is her "normal country" also her country of nationality?

Comment: Yes it’s her country of nationality..she’s never had any other nationality it’s my mistake.

Comment: I don't understand. You say that you answered "no" instead of "yes", but then you say in the comments that she's never had any other nationality. So didn't you answer the question correctly?

Comment: She has never had any other nationality .so my mistake was answering “no” to the question “have they always had the same nationality?”. Then the pop up question was “what nationality was she when she gave birth to you? And I put her only nationality which is where we come from. I hope this makes more sense